# Flutter & Firebase: Is it possible to get specific field of for each document? (Not whole field then filter it)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For the example [image]

I want to get the age field of all documents.
At the moment, I am using:

```
await collection.get().then((value) {
      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in value.docs) {
        print(doc.get('age'));
      }
    });
```

This method gets all fields of the document and then get specific field by using `.get('age')`. I don't want to get big data and then filter it.
The firebase has the `.doc('')` function to get specific documents but I don't found something like `.field([''])` to get these fields that I want.

Is it possible to get the specific fields that I selected?

Comment: This is not possible with the client SDK atm. You would have to fetch data through a Cloud Function to get send specific data only to client or denormalize the data. Checkout the linked answer for more information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fact. This helps me decide to separate this field into the new collection.